# Span on top of one another

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make these spans on top of each other but not so luck,

http://jsfiddle.net/76NNp/79/

```
<td class="rtf hov">
    <div>Investment</div>
    <div class="mub eub">
        <span style="float:left">Test</span>
        <span style="float:right;">I want to be on Top</span>
        <span style="float:right; color:green">I want to be on bottom</span>
    </div>
</td>
```

Desired result,

[image]

Comment: When you say on top of each other, do you mean vertically, or stacked using zIndex?

Comment: @yarond like this http://jsfiddle.net/76NNp/86/

Comment: yup, sort of - http://jsfiddle.net/76NNp/89/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to this way

**Css**

```
.left{
    float:left;
}
.right{
    float:right;
}
.clr{
    clear:both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="msub estextsub">
    <span class="left">Investment</span>

    <span  class="right">I want to be on Top</span>
    <div class="clr"></div>
     <span  class="left">Test</span>
    <span  class="right">I want to be on bottom</span>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/76NNp/88/)

Comment: Thanks Rohit, but it moved them down as well :(

Comment: Can u give me more details or give me same samle as like image

Comment: added it now in my ques

Answer (score 1):

what about using position - like here
http://jsfiddle.net/76NNp/87/

```
<span style="position:absolute;top:0; right:0">I want to be on Top</span>
<span style="position:absolute;bottom:0; right:0">I want to be on bottom</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add clear: both in both span. Here is working code:

```css
.rtddef {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<td class="rtddef es1hov">
    <div>Investment</div>
    <div class="msub estextsub">
        <span style="float:left">Test</span>
        <span style="float:right;clear:both;">I want to be on Top</span>
        <span style="float:right; color:green;clear:both;">I want to be on bottom</span>
    </div>
</td>
```